# difference between method and class field when setting table value

Tags: angular, primeng

I had a problem where I couldn't select and copy text from a table because the table was refreshed and rendered every time I clicked on it. When I change version one where I use the method to set the table value to version two where I use the class field, the problem is solved. Could someone explain to me why? This table was placed in a modal dialog.

Component:

```
@Input() details: any;
protected metadata: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.metadata = this.getMetadata();
}

getMetadata() {
  return [{
    date: this.details.revisionInfo.timestamp
  }];
}
```

Version1:

```
<p-table [value]="getMetadata()">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{rowData.date}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Version2:

```
<p-table [value]="metadata">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{rowData.date}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: What does `getMetadata()` do? is this a http request?

Comment: It gets some data from input() . I placed the code it in the "Component" listing. This is a simplified version, but it behaves the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you are doing `getMetadata()` the method is called on every change detection. It may be not an issue at all, but it could also bring huge performance degradation for your component. It depends on the exact cases.

If you can afford to learn and understand change detection - do it and you will be able to distinguish between cases where it is possible to leave a method call in the template. But in general it is better to save value as a component property and refer to it in the template.

Comment: Thank you, ok, I'll read more because I wonder why the component reloads even though getMetadata returns the same thing every time, the data does not change.

Comment: the data doesn't change, but the completely new array(containing the same data) is created. for everything in angular it is a brand new piece of data.

Comment: there is a possibility to add trackBy functionality for certain things (for example ngFor directive) so it would be able to reuse the old rendered piece with the new data.

Comment: ok, so when angular checking for changes after clicking, angular calls the getMetadata() method, which returns a new object (with a new reference), so the value Input() for the table component has changed, which in turn causes the component (the table) to be rerendered. When I use component property this is the same value, so table is not rerendered

Comment: yes. that is correct